# Incongruencia con Calendar.dateComponents en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3, date, calendar

Tengo la variable `fecha` que al hacer un `print` muestra por consola: `2016-11-20 23:00:00 +0000`

El problema es que al realizar esto:

```
let auxCalendar = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday, .day, .weekdayOrdinal, .month], from: fecha)
print("*\(fecha)*")
print("\n***\n\(auxCalendar)\n\(fecha)\n***\n")
```

Me muestra esto:

> *2016-11-20 23:00:00 +0000*
>
> *** 
>   month: 11 day: 21 weekday: 2 weekdayOrdinal: 3 isLeapMonth: false
>   2016-11-20 23:00:00 +0000 
>   
> ***

Como veis hay una incongruencia, pues le he pasado la fecha con dia 20 y el me retorna el dia 21

La variable `calendar` la inicializo asi:

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
```

Comment: Te está contando el lunes por algun motivo, ya que `weekDay` es `2` y ese calendario empieza en domingo

Comment: Si, me suma 1 dia a todas las fechas con las que he hecho pruebas @lois6b

Comment: Todas las fechas tenian la misma hora?

Comment: Si, `23:00:00` @lois6b

Comment: Puede ser una chorrada pero puedes poner por ejemplo las 10am y probar?

Comment: Hice una edición de esta pregunta pero no se ha aprobado. Era sobre la palabra _inconcluencia_ que no significa nada, debería ser _incongruencia_

Answer (score 1):

Hace falta que declares la zona horaria de tu región geográfica.

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_MX")
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Mexico_City")
```